# Installing a topshelf service using powershell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to install a topshelf service using powershell but am really struggling to get powershell to run the installer.

```
Function EnsureTopshelfService([string]$serviceName, [string]$servicePath){
    $service = get-service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    if ($service –ne $null){
        "$serviceName is already installed on this server";
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Installing $serviceName...";

        #the problem is here
        & "`"$servicepath`" install --sudo"
    }
}
```

When i run this command i get the following

> Installing test... 
>   & : The term '"c:\A Test\Test.exe" install --sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At
>   C:\Users\luke.mcgregor\Documents\Test.ps1:11 char:11
>   +         & "`"$servicepath`" install --sudo"
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("c:\A Test\Test.exe" install --sudo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Running `"c:\A Test\Test.exe" install --sudo` at a command prompt works fine so its an issue with how im calling off to an existing program. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here? I'm pretty new to powershell so I'm guessing its a pretty simple thing.

**EDIT:**
The following is a working example of the above

```
Function EnsureTopshelfService([string]$serviceName, [string]$servicePath){
    $service = get-service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    if ($service –ne $null){
        "$serviceName is already installed on this server";
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Installing $serviceName...";

        & "$servicepath" install --sudo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tokenize by delimiting with a space. So -

```
& "`"$servicepath`" install --sudo"
```

Should be 3 tokens -

```
& $servicepath install --sudo
```

The ampersand is the PowerShell call operator. Anything after it works the same as if you had typed it in a CMD.exe window. If a single token has a space in it, you'll need to quote it.

Check out more info about the call operator [here](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, but I'm not too sure why. I thought this just worked by jamming a string containing a command at the call operator. This seems not to be the case? Does the call operator take an array of arguments and infer first to be command path and subsequent ones to be specific arguments? Why is this different from just passing a string?

Comment: You got it @Luke, the call operator syntax is `& "[path]\program.exe" [arguments]`, where arguments may be space delimited strings or an array of strings. And thanks for the push :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the (weird/crazy/take-your-pick) syntax, add a colon between the argument name and value.

So assuming you have the EXE built with topshelf at `C:\Services\ItJustWorks\ItJustWorks.exe` then you can run the following from powershell:

```
PS C:\Services\ItJustWorks> .\ItJustWorks.exe install -servicename:"ItJustWorks"
```